# Async Panel binding errors

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I am creating an async panel in angular2 that will basically wrap and existing component and only make it visible when the actual observable is complete.

so my HTML looks like this..

```
<div class="async-container">
    <div *ngIf="state === 'loading'" class="loading">Loading</div>
    <div *ngIf="state === 'error'" class="loading">Request failed</div>
    <ng-content *ngIf="state === 'complete'"></ng-content>
</div>
```

and the actual usage is something like..

```
<async-panel [service]="example.getObject(model.id)" (complete)="onLoad($event)">
    <div class="pul-right">
        {{model.user.id}}
    </div>
</async-panel>
```

as you can see, its very simple and the ng-content is only visible when the it should be but even with the ngIf I still get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined` before the observable has even finished.

the user value is set on the (complete) event of the panel

```
 this.service.subscribe(
            (data) => {
                this.complete.emit(data);
                this.state = 'complete';
            },
            (error) => {
                this.error.emit(error);
                this.state = 'error';
            }
        );
```

Is there any way around this or a better solution? Angular seems to be parsing the transcluded content even before its rendered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the Elvis operator:

```
{{model?.user?.id}}
```

The problem is that the content you provide as input (ng-content) is evaluate within the calling component, i.e. the one that uses the `async-panel` component. So you need to be sure that `model` is defined when trying to use its `user` field.

Comment: The model will never be defined at that point, its why we are using an async panel to show a loading indicator for example - is there a way that I am missing here that would be a better implementation?

Comment: Where `model` comes from? When the `user` attribute of this object is set?

Comment: So model will be set on the onLoad callback that is defined as a param of the async component ( I have updated the code slightly above to show how the callback is fired to the component )

Comment: I see your approach. I think that if you want to use ng-content you need the Elvis operator. The reason is that everything is resolved in the calling template and `model` isn't there at the beginning since it's loaded later. That being said, there is another approach based on template that prevent from this.

Comment: Hmm, that approach too me seems wrong - what if the template is rather big, I could have a hundred 100, surely there is something we are both missing?